# Is there any stable fork of BURG available for Raring?

Tags: installation, burg

I had a look at [BURG wiki](http://code.google.com/p/burg/wiki/InstallUbuntu) for installing it on 13.04 and it said that BURG is supported for jaunty (9.04), karmic (9.10), lucid (10.04) and maverick (10.10). Is there any fork available for raring (13.04)?

Comment: The wiki page probably has not been updated since is says "
Updated Jul 2, 2010" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been compiled 25 weeks ago for the last time. So the newest version is  `1.98+20100623-2.3` (2013-03-27). (Yes, I know you asked for stable ;) )

The PPA for this is ...

```
ppa:n-muench/burg
```

Command line installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
sudo update-burg
```

Or by editing your sources list:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu raring main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu raring main
```

The actual software for this PPA and 13.04 can be found here: http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu/dists/raring/